# If statement versus switch statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

I have an interesting case for everyone who thinks they know javascript and its switch and if statement so well. This is how it should normally work:

```
var a = 1;
if (a == 1) alert("true");
```

This is extremely simplified. With the switch statement, it goes like this:

```
var a = 1;
switch (a)
{
  case 1: alert("true");
}
```

However, when I attempt to do the switch statement, correctly as far as I can tell, to replace a lot of if statements, I suddenly can't seem to make it work. Offcourse, this question has been asked a lot of times, yet all codes are different and there is no consistent pattern for that, so I couldn't find it myself online.

The code below is supposed to output that the hero is NOT confirmed to have correct values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  Skilllevel = [0,20,80,150,300,800,1000,1200,1400,1600,2000,2250,2500,2750,3000,4000,4200,4400,4700,5000];
  Merclevel = [0,150];
  A = 0;
  B = "";
  hero = "";
  heroesMain = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,16,0,18,16,16,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  heroesCost = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,1,0,0,1.5,1,1,2,1,1,1.5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  function skillcalc()
  {
    var confirmed = "";
    var skillQ = document.getElementById("SkillQ").value;
    var skillA = document.getElementById("SkillA").value;
    if (skillQ == "max") skillQ = 20;
    else if (skillQ == "min") skillQ = 1;
    else if (skillQ < 0) skillQ = 0;
    if (skillA > 20) skillA = 20;
    else if (skillA == "tomin")
    {
      waarde = document.getElementById("heroes").value;
      hero = document.getElementById("heroes");
      /*if (waarde == 1 || waarde == 2 || waarde == 3 || waarde == 4 || waarde == 5 || waarde == 6 || waarde == 7 || waarde == 8 || waarde == 9 || waarde == 10 || waarde == 11 || waarde == 12 || waarde == 13 || waarde == 14 || waarde == 15 || waarde == 16 || waarde == 17 || waarde == 18 || waarde == 19 || waarde == 20 || waarde == 22 || waarde == 22 || waarde == 23 || waarde == 24 || waarde == 25 || waarde == 26) confirmed = "NOT ";*/
//switch statement not working
switch (waarde)
{
case 1: confirmed = "NOT ";
}
      hero = hero.options[hero.selectedIndex].text;
      skillA = heroesMain[waarde];
      if (heroesMain[waarde] == 0 || heroesCost[waarde] == 0) B+="I don\'t know some of it, but here it comes:<br />";
     // if (waarde == 1 || waarde == 2) confirmed = "NOT ";
      B += "The " + hero + " costs " + heroesCost[waarde] + " rage at level " + heroesMain[waarde] + ". <br />WARNING! Everything is still being tested. <br /> This hero is " + confirmed + "confirmed to have correct values.";
    }
    else if (skillA < 0) skillA = 0;
    while (skillA > skillQ)
    {
      A+=Skilllevel[skillQ];
      skillQ++;
    }
    WriteNew = document.getElementById("writeNew");
    if (WriteNew.checked)
    {
      document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML+= "The # of rings required = " + A  + "<br />"+ B;
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML= "The # of rings required = " + A  + "<br />"+ B;
    }
    A=0;
    B="";
  }
</script>
Your hero: 
<select id="heroes">
<option value="0" selected="selected">[Any epic hero]</option>
<option value="1">Air Elite</option>
<option value="2">Glory Priestress</option>
<option value="3">Blockhead</option>
<option value="4">Carol d'Belle</option>
<option value="5">Blitz Bomber</option>
<option value="6">Pounder</option>
<option value="7">Hydrasaur</option>
<option value="8">Renee Ven</option>
<option value="9">Arctic Lord</option>
<option value="10">Pan Goli</option>
<option value="11">Sapphirix</option>
<option value="12">Dark Rider</option>
<option value="13">Great Sage</option>
<option value="14">Abyss Demon</option>
<option value="15">Landslide</option>
<option value="16">Ambrosia</option>
<option value="17">Skull Mage</option>
<option value="18">Chiron</option>
<option value="19">Djinni</option>
<option value="20">Demon Slayer</option>
<option value="21">Enchantress</option>
<option value="22">The Berserker</option>
<option value="23">Savage Chief</option>
<option value="24">Won Ton</option>
<option value="25">Arcane Caster</option>
<option value="26">Toxic Shaman</option>
</select>
<br />
Your skilllevel: <input type="text" id="SkillQ"><br />
Required skilllevel: <input type="text" id="SkillA"><br />
<label for="writeNew">Write New?</label><input type="checkbox" id="writeNew" /><br />
<button onclick="skillcalc()">Calculate</button>

<p id="Answer"></p>
```

I requested the browser to alert back the value of waarde, the value of which this is about.

Here's a screenshot of how it should look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfF5s.png

Here's how it actually looks like: (it doesn't say that its values are NOT correct)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lYAd.png

I am willing to respond to as many questions as you may have to this interesting scene. Maybe I am overlooking something, but I am not quite sure what it is.

Regards, Patrick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the value you used in the switch-statement is text.

Try it in the console:

```
var a = '1'; 
switch(a) {
    case 1: alert('Number'); 
    case '1': alert('Text');
}
```

You should probably use `switch(parseInt(a))`.

Comment: Or better yet, `parseInt(a, 10)`. Don't forget your radix.

Comment: @dave. Or `switch(+a)` using unary operator

Comment: Your answer solved the cause and User6188402, Dave and Rogier Spieker finetuned the bits that are going to make the code just a little more future proof and a little less unreadable. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you've grown accustomed to javascript comparing what you intend, not what you say.

This phenomenon is called `type coercion` and it happens when you use the `==` (2x =) operator instead of `===` (3x =).

When you use `==`, for example in `'1' == 1`, one of the values is converted into the type of the other (this is called `coercion`), so - in this example - the actual comparison is `'1' == '1'`, which results in `true`.

If you use `===` to compare, the value *must* be equal in both value *and* type, so `'1' === 1` will result in `false`.

The `switch` doesn't do this `coercion`, so it will behave as if you are comparing using `===` (where both value *and* type must be equal).

In order for the `switch` to work correctly, you must ensure the value fed to `switch(value)` has the same type as the values you use in the `case`.

Your code takes a value from the DOM (a form), using

```
waarde = document.getElementById("heroes").value
```

Which will always be a string type, so you either must use strings in you case (e.g. `case '1':`) or convert the value obtained from the DOM into a number, (e.g. `waarde = parseInt(..., 10)` ([the radix argument is important!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)))

[read more on coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md)